# Three.js ported to native code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, three.js

I've been playing with WebGL quite a bit lately and I really dig [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).  It's really lightweight and just serves as something that makes wrangling most of the GL calls a bit easier, and provides a quick way of creating basic primatives like a sphere.

Now, in native land, it seems that all the frameworks want to be so much more than that. Things like Oolong, UDK, Unity, Cocos, etc.  I did a bit of googling, and the closest thing I could find was [iSGL3D](http://isgl3d.com/) but I'm not thoroughly convinced it is the right answer.

Is there something more similar to Three.js that is written in native C, C++ or Objective-C that I can't find?

Comment: Have you looked at Apples own GLKit? Although lower level than Three.js, it is still a very nice framework imho that simplifies your graphics code substantially.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a port of three to C++: https://github.com/jdduke/three_cpp

> Core - 75% complete (TODO: Morph targets, shadows, plugin support)
>
> Extras - 5-10% complete (TODO: Pretty much everything)
>
> Examples - 25% complete (TODO: Examples involving morph targets an)

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for a strict graphics engine only, in the same direction as OpenGL (in comparison to DirectX which again wants to be so much more than that). I'd advise [Ogre3D for iPhone](http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre%20iPhone) as the philosophy behind Ogre3d is to be a strict graphics engine.

The other one that comes to mind is recently perused [MoSync mobile sdk](http://www.mosync.com/) which offers excellent [OpenGL](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html/class_m_a_util_1_1_g_l_moblet.html)  support across a wide range of platforms (albeit limited; to maintain portability).

If you're more interested in loading shaders and having the graphics engine manage the rest, I'd pick Ogre3D for iPhone.

You can always take the initiative (if you have the time of course) to write your own or start off from the ones mentioned here!

Or you can use a JavaScript engine ([JSAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSAPI_User_Guide) for example) in a C++ editor and then move three.js on top of that. This is great as you'll only update the JSAPI and Three.js without breaking functionalities and your C++/JSThree engine will stay up to date with minimal maintenance.

Just some ideas of course!

Comment: Ogre seems more heavy handed than iSGL3D :(

Comment: @slf: Yup sure is. Although in perspective, the new and coming generations of devices (tegra > 2, A5 > etc.) will be more suited as OpenGL ES 2.0 is becoming standard in the mobile platforms.

Comment: Ogre... very, very bad experience with it. Its installation is a mess (I've tried over Fedora, it had probably be the worst package installation evar), and even its documentation isn't complete/up-to-date/accurate/nooby-friendly.

Comment: Well jumping on Ogre3d or C/C++ graphics engines demands tinkering and rewiring. It's expected by the very nature of game development. Maybe you can submit a Fedora port path to the project. That would be helpful for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Although I would also prefer to see a port of three.js for iOS, recently stumbled up on iSGL3d (http://isgl3d.com/).

This project serves a simple, encapsuled way to build an manipulate an opengl scene graph by code. Otherwise than some creative coding frameworks like cinder, iSGL3d comes in pure Objective C.

Works well for me yet.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I asked about in my question?

Comment: +1 for libcinder, the cinder::gl is close to what I'm talking about, but it's still kind of beefy for my taste

Answer (score 3):

You could also give [Ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta) a go. They just added WebGL/three.js support.

https://github.com/phoboslab/Ejecta/tree/next

Answer (score 1):

Three_cpp is good, but has stopped updating since 3 years ago. It does not support VS version below 2012.

Ogre is another good choice, which is much similar to the logic of Threejs:)
And the official site provides a very detailed tutorial, making it easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found a [stripped down version of SIO2 called GFX](http://gfx.sio2interactive.com/) that looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for strictly ease-of-use, I'd highly recommend [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/). It's cross-platform (Windows, Unix, Mac), really easy to use, has extensive documentation, and a nice community around it.